# How to remove a set of entries from a Tk window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am building a Python desktop application using tkinter library. The application must create a list of entries based on a spinbox value when generate_button clicked.

I am wondering how can I delete the list of entries and recreate new entries if the user changed the spinbox value and clicked the generate_button a second time.

Following is my code ...

```
CORRECT_ENTRIES = []
def generate_entries():
    n = int(spinbox.get())
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        entry = Entry(width=40)
        entry.grid(row=3+i, column=0, pady=5, padx=5)

        CORRECT_ENTRIES.append(entry)


window = Tk()

# Spinbox
spinbox = Spinbox(from_=3, to=15, width=5)
spinbox.grid(row=2, column=1)

# Button
generate_btn = Button(text="Generate Entries", command=generate_entries)
generate_btn.grid(row=2, column=3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is looking for a solution for a such issue I found the following solution and It worked properly hopefully:

```
def remove_old_entries():
    for entry in COOKIES:
        entry.grid_remove()
    for entry in EXTRA_COOKIES:
        entry.grid_remove()


def generate_entries():
    global x, COOKIES, EXTRA_COOKIES
    remove_old_entries()
    COOKIES = []
    EXTRA_COOKIES = []
    n = int(spinbox.get())
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        r_entry = Entry(width=40)
        r_entry.grid(row=3 + i, column=1, pady=5, padx=5)
        COOKIES.append(r_entry)

    m = int(spinbox_extra.get())
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        entry = Entry(width=40)
        entry.grid(row=3 + i, column=2, pady=5)
        EXTRA_COOKIES.append(entry)
```

I called this function inside the generate_entries() function